# ASPNET CORE Ajax Post results in 400 Bad Request

Tags: ajax, post, asp.net-core

I am working on  ASP.NET Zero  which is built on ASP.NET Core.
I was getting a bad request error when I used KendoUI Upload control on one of my pages. After lot of research and investigation, I realized the HTTP POST Ajax request is failing with 400 bad request error. My code samples below have some commented line for other scenarios I test. None of the existing posts in stack over flow  solved my issue. I  Below is my ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "/test/TestCall",
            type: 'Post',
           /* data: JSON.stringify({ "Param1": "test" }),
            dataType:"json",
            processData: false,  */// tell jQuery not to process the data
            contentType: "application/json",  // tell jQuery not to set contentType
            success: function (result) {
                var res = result;
            },
            error: function (jqXHR) {
                var z = 3;
            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
                var x = 10;
            }
        });
```

My Controller code is: I also tried without extending from MyTestProjectControllerBase and just using the Controller base class. It did not work.

```
public class TestController : MyTestProjectControllerBase
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TestCall()
    {
        //return Content("Name is:" );
        return new ContentResult() { Content = "test" };
    }
}
```

What am I missing? I tried using postman and I see this additional  information
'Request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax'

could not figure it out after spending good 8 hours on this issue. Not sure if the issue is with Asp.net core or asp.net zero. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Update after checking the comments by shyju:
Startup.cs file has the following code that enables AntiForgeryTokenAttribute

```
 services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
        }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

Updates to the ajax call and view based on answer by shyju:

```
  $("#backBtn").on("click", function (e) {
        var t = $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/test/TestCall",
            type: 'Post',
           /* data: JSON.stringify({ "Param1": "test" }),
            dataType:"json",
            processData: false,  */
            contentType: "application/json",  
            headers: {
                "RequestVerificationToken": t
            },
            success: function (result) {
                var res = result;
            },
            error: function (jqXHR) {
                var z = 3;
            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
                var x = 10;
            }
        });
    });
```

My view looks like this now:removed rest of the html

```
<div id="container">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="k-edit-field label">Vendor Name</div>
</div
```

Comment: With the code you shared, it should not throw a 400 response. I just copied and pasted your code to a local project and it returns 200 OK for me. Looks like you are not sharing some code which is causing the 400 response. Do you have a `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute on your action method ?

Comment: No. this project has a lot existing files. but the controller I created has nothing more than what I copied here. ValidateAntiForgeryToken is not on my action method.
Have you tested my code on aspnet core?

Comment: hi, I just looked up for the ValidateAntiForgeryToken in the entire solution. startup.cs has the follwoing code
services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
            }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

Comment: can you add it to the question. I will post a solution now

Answer (score 18):

Looks like you have `AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute` filter applied globally. That means when an HTTP Post action method is called(normal or ajax), the framework will check the submitted request data and if it does not find a valid anti forgery token(`RequestVerificationToken` header), it will be considered a bad request and a 400 response will be sent back.

To fix this problem, you can explicitly read the value of `__RequestVerificationToken` hidden input (generated by the form tag helper) and send that in your ajax request headers.

```
var t = $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();

$.ajax({
    url: "/test/TestCall",
    type: 'Post',
    headers:
    {
        "RequestVerificationToken": t
    },
    success: function (result) {
        alert("Success");
        var res = result;
    },
    error: function (jqXHR) {
        var z = 3;
    },
    complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
        var x = 10;
    }
});
```

You can make the code more robust by injecting the `IAntiforgery` implementation to the view/page and using the `GetAndStoreTokens` method.

Add this to your view

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Xsrf
@functions{
public string GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()
{
    return Xsrf.GetAndStoreTokens(Context).RequestToken;
}
}
```

and call this GetAntiXsrfRequestToken function to get the value in your javascript ( which is inside the view file)

```
headers:
{
    "RequestVerificationToken": '@GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()'
},
```

Comment: Thank you for help. This did not fix the problem. however, if I comment out the global filter to test, that allowed the post request to pass through. 
You identified the problem correctly. but the solution is not working for some reason. i can see the token generated and passed to ajax call. will update the ajax new ajax call in the question

Comment: Is it sending the needed header value ? Tried your code and worked fine for me.

Comment: I checked in under network tab in chrome; request header has  RequestVerificationToken set to the token. Is there anything else I should verify?

Comment: Do you have any other filters on your server side which might be returning a 400 response.

Comment: not sure. what should I look for? its a asp.net zero source code has a lot of files

Comment: I do not see anyother filters in startup.cs. will keep searching

Comment: Thanks for this explanation @Shyju. It helped me solve the same problem. Something I do not understand though is the fact that my ajax call has been working for weeks without using any headers to specify the Token. Suddendly today I got a http 400 error. Why is that? I have not done any changes regarding token neither within the Controller, Model or View..

Answer (score 3):

In Core -- make sure your `<form>` tag includes `method="post"`.

The method is required to invoke the form tag helper which automatically adds the antiforgery token to the form.  (I accidentally left off the method and didn't notice because I was ajax-posting it.)

Answer (score 3):

In Net Core RazorPages, you will have to pass AntiForgeryToken with JQuery Ajax Post request. if you have a Form tag with Method=Post then you do not have to worry about sending it.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"?Handler=Update",
    dataType:"json",
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
      xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
    },
    success: function(result){
      // do something
    }
});
```

Then in your Razor Page

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery
@inject IAntiforgery antiforgery
@{
   var token = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext).RequestToken;
}
```

Be sure to add

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

Then in your StartUp.cs inside ConfigureServices method, add

```
services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the header with `X-XSRF-TOKEN`.

For [ABP Intercept XMLHttpRequest](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/XSRF-CSRF-Protection#intercept-xmlhttprequest).

> Since all libraries use JavaScript's native AJAX object, XMLHttpRequest, you can define a simple interceptor to add the token to the header:

```
(function (send) {
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function (data) {
        this.setRequestHeader(abp.security.antiForgery.tokenHeaderName, abp.security.antiForgery.getToken());
        return send.call(this, data);
    };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);
```

For `abp.security.antiForgery.tokenHeaderName`, its default value is `X-XSRF-TOKEN`